# Making actions based on video audio codec

Tags: bash

Currently, I have a simple script that will detect video audio codec using ffmpeg and output a message specifing if the codec is mp4 or aac. Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.mp4; do
    OUTPUT=$(ffmpeg -i '$i' 2>&1 | grep -o 'Audio:.*' | cut -f2 -d' ' | awk '{print $0}' | tr -d ,)
    if [[ $OUTPUT == "mp3" ]]; then
        echo "${i} = audio codec mp3"
    fi
    if [[ $OUTPUT == "aac" ]]; then
        echo "${i} = audio codec aac"
    fi
done
```

But this script isn't working! There are no errors and I don't know what should I do to solve this. Also, `ffmpeg -i <input.mp4> 2>&1 | grep -o 'Audio:.*' | cut -f2 -d' ' | awk '{print $0}' | tr -d ,` returns aac or mp3, this line is working perfeclty! I guess that the problem is related to `if case`, but as I've said, I'm unable to solve this alone, can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: Replace the single quotes surrounding `$i` with double quotes in the `ffmpeg` line.

Comment: As an aside, if you are using Awk anyway, you [might as well get rid of `grep` and `cut` and `tr`.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) Also, don't use uppercase for your private variables, and probably don't capture the result into a variable at all. 
 `case $(ffmpeg -i '$i' 2>&1 | awk '/Audio:/ { a =$1; sub(/,/, "", a); print a }') in mp3) echo mp3;; ... esac`

Answer (score 0):

> > if [[ $OUTPUT == "mp3" ]]; then 
> > if [[ $OUTPUT == "aac" ]]; then

Replace this with 
if [[ "$OUTPUT" = "mp3" ]]; then 
if [[ "$OUTPUT" = "aac" ]]; then